# relation "table" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, permissions, schema, functions, plpgsql

i created the following schema , inside that schema i created a table and inserted a some values.

After that i created a function that get a value in the table based on an ID.

Here is all the declarations :

```sql
CREATE SCHEMA pckg_50d_facture;
CREATE TABLE pckg_50d_facture.valeur(val_id text PRIMARY KEY, val text);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pckg_50d_facture.const(id text) RETURNS text AS $body$
DECLARE
result text;
BEGIN
  --EXECUTE 'SELECT val FROM pckg_50d_facture.valeur WHERE val_id = id' INTO result USING checked_user, checked_date;

    SELECT val INTO result FROM pckg_50d_facture.valeur WHERE val_id = id;

 return result;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
;
```

But when i call the function **const** i get the following error :

`ERROR:  relation "valeur" does not exist`

I tried to Grant some rights as follow :

```sql
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA pckg_50d_facture TO PUBLIC;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA pckg_50D_facture TO PUBLIC;
```

but still not working.

Comment: Please tag your PostgreSQL version.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is unrelated to privileges. The table `valeur` simply cannot be found. There must be some kind of confusion. My educated guess:

You call the function without schema qualification and accidentally execute a different function of the same name, because `pckg_50d_facture` is not in the `search_path` (or is there but in a later position). See:

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the “current schema”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067777/939860)

Or you connected to the wrong database / database cluster by mistake.